# adding where clause in javascript

Tags: javascript, picture-library

```
var PicLibraryURL = "/SC/SW/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List=%7B9D30BD4A%2DBA0F%4ED2VM%2DBEBB%2D8CEC5D74A29B%7D";
```

How do I add a where clause to above javascript?

I have a flag y/n column `ShowInRotator` in the pic libray and like to only fetch record where `ShowInRotator=Yes` (or true or 1, whatever it is).

I would also like to add additional text with the image rotator (the comments column in picture library has the text that I like display during image rotator.

```
http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/Pages/ImageRotator.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a View with a filter based on the criteria you want and then include the View parameter in your query string:

```
&View={ViewGuid}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will certain try this. Actually, I do have a custom view where I added the active=1 filter. BTW, do you know how to put a link or link on the image SP OOTB picture library slide show web part

Comment: I don't think it's possible OOB.